# UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace doesn't work in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

In iOS 11 the `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` bar button system item type doesn't create any spacing. I was using it to distribute space evenly between bar button items. Is this desired behavior in iOS 11 or a bug? Is there a workaround?

There aren't any notes about any changes for `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` in iOS 11 in the current documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem/uibarbuttonsystemitemflexiblespace

Here is an example that in iOS 10 will show three bar button items that are evenly spaced across the entire width of the navigation item.

```
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
NSArray *items = @[leftButton, flex, middleButton, flex, rightButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:items animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I doubt the issue is directly related to `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`. iOS 11 may have changed how it lays out buttons on a nav bar using either `leftBarButtonItems` or `rightBarButtonItems`. I bet if you set that same array of items on a toolbar it would work as expected.

Comment: Same issue for me. Other posts have hinted that this might be due to autolayout overriding your UIBarButton array items.

Comment: Same issue for me. Does no-one at Apple use `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative spacer for UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544961/negative-spacer-for-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-on-ios-11)