# iOS 11 Popover Presentation Issue in Multi-tasking Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uipopovercontroller, xcode9

Keeping popover in open state. Then, when I try to switch to 2/3 screen mode and change the position of center BarButtonItem with fixed space BarButtonItem in viewWillTrainsition, my popover tool-tip moves to the previous location of barButtonItem.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    if (size.width>size.height) {
        _fixedSpace.width = 280;
    } else {
        _fixedSpace.width = 80;
    }
} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

}];}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try by dismissing current popover before moving to other screen ?

Answer (score 0):

From iOS11, bar button item is using constraint instead of frames. So try giving a constraint to each bar button item. It might doesn't reflect visually but it plays a major role in producing this kind of issue.

Try using below code to set the constraint:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
{
  _fixedSpace.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0).isActive = true
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no width anchor for barButton.

Comment: My apologies, I had custom view which supports widthAnchor so thought it should work. Anyway give a try to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544961/negative-spacer-for-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-on-ios-11

Answer (score 0):

I replicated same scenario and I found a fix for this as below:

```
[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    if (size.width > size.height) {
        fixedSpace.width = 280;
    } else {
        fixedSpace.width = 80;
    }
} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:barBtn.frame fromView:barBtn];
    popover.sourceRect = rect;
}];
```

Try to reset the sourceRect property in the completion block.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question I want to propose a simple solution for this :

I have took a Viewcontroller and PopoverView in storyboard. Viewcontroller will work as main view controller where as PopoverView will work to display as popover.
(Caution : Don’t Forget to set Explicit Content Size for PopoverView in StoryBoard) for more reference you can see attached screen shot of my storyboard.

[image]

Here is sample source code of Viewcontroller in which you will find Popoverview position will change as per the right button frame change.

This code is developed using **Objective C**

**ViewController.h**

```
    //
    //  ViewController.h
    //  SOPopoverControllerDemo
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 08/01/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Test User All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController


    @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    //
    //  ViewController.m
    //  SOPopoverControllerDemo
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 08/01/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Test User All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController () <UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *leftToolBarBtn;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightToolBarBtn;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *flexibleBtn;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *bottomToolBar;
    @property (weak,nonatomic) UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverController;


    @end



    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (self.view.frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.height) {
            self.rightToolBarBtn.width = 200;
            self.leftToolBarBtn.width = 200;
        } else {
            self.rightToolBarBtn.width = 150;
            self.leftToolBarBtn.width = 150;
        }

    }

    - (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
        [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
        [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
            if (size.width > size.height) {
                _rightToolBarBtn.width = 200;
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
                [self rightToolBarBtnTapped:_rightToolBarBtn];
            } else {
                _rightToolBarBtn.width = 150;
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
                [self rightToolBarBtnTapped:_rightToolBarBtn];
            }
        } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

        }];
    }

    - (IBAction)rightToolBarBtnTapped:(id)sender {


        //Grab the controller for popover
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopoverView"];

        if (self.view.frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.height ) {
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
        } else {
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 100);
        }


        controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

        // configure the Popover presentation controller
        _popOverController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
        _popOverController.delegate = self;
        _popOverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
        _popOverController.barButtonItem = self.rightToolBarBtn;

        }


    //--------------------------------------------------
    #pragma mark ->  UIPopOverController Delegate
    //--------------------------------------------------

    - (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
        NSLog(@"Popover Did Dismissed");
    }


    @end
```

**PopoverView.h**

```
    //
    //  PopoverView.h
    //  SOPopoverControllerDemo
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 08/01/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Test User All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface PopoverView : UIViewController

    @end
```

**PopoverView.m**

```
    //
    //  PopoverView.m
    //  SOPopoverControllerDemo
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 08/01/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Test User All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "PopoverView.h"

    @interface PopoverView ()

    @end

    @implementation PopoverView

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```