# iOS 11 - how to change the position of rightBarButtonItems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

the code in iOS 10 or earlier is worked

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setTitle:@"yyyyy"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn1];

UIBarButtonItem *fixed = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixed.width = -22;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems  = @[fixed, item1];
```

[image]

if i want to do the same thing in iOS 11, what can i do fo it?

Comment: What do you see in the iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 10? And why is the width negative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative spacer for UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544961/negative-spacer-for-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-on-ios-11)

Comment: @rmaddy because the code 'fixed.width = -22;'

Comment: Yes, I see that code, that's why I asked. Why are you setting the width to the negative value? What does that accomplish? And what happened when you want your app on the iPhone 7 Plus simulator with iOS 10?

Comment: @rmaddy i want to adjust the position of the 'yyyy' barbutton,in iOS10 ,i can do that, so i need help to do that in iOS 11.

Comment: @rmaddy, negative width used to work before iOS 11, it was used to adjust the position of the buttons (for example if you wanted them to have zero margin from the screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have acomplished this by subclassing UINavigationBar:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InsetButtonsNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end
```

and setting layoutMargins

```
#import "InsetButtonsNavigationBar.h"

@implementation InsetButtonsNavigationBar

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {

        view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);

    }

}

@end
```