# UIToolbar left and right spacing when rotating device in IOS11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm having a strange issue with the padding of the UIToolbar since iOS11. When the device is rotated the left and right padding of the toolbar gets bigger(watch example below).

It doesn't matter if the device is in portrait or landscape mode before the rotation. The extra spacing only occurs after rotating. I think it's an auto resizing issue or something.

**View Debugger before rotation (correct spacing):**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wigv1et88t1mvn/Schermafdruk%202018-01-31%2015.51.05.png?dl=0

**View Debugger after rotation (wrong spacing):**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gnqi6hzv5czcnw/Schermafdruk%202018-01-31%2020.59.48.png?dl=0

**Example:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7jbmbsuorump5e/spacing-toolbar.gif?dl=0

I'm using a toolbar class to create the buttons inside the toolbar.
In the xcode interface the option 'Autoresize Subview' is checked.

**Code:**

```
class ToolbarClass: UIToolbar {

    //Set height of toolbar
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        size.height = 60
        return size
    }

    //Toolbar settings
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        //Default
        self.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        self.sizeToFit()

        //Buttons ios11+

        //Space
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let spaceBetween:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        spaceBetween.width = 1.0

        let nameSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        nameSpace.width = 10

        //Logo
        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "MBS-Logo")
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
        logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -46, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54)
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let logoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54))
        logoView.clipsToBounds = false
        logoView.layer.cornerRadius = logoView.frame.width / 2
        logoView.addSubview(logoImageView)
        let logoImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)
        logoImg.customView = logoView

        //Profile
        let profileImage = UIImage(named: "No-Profile")
        let profileImageView = UIImageView(image: profileImage)
        profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.width / 2
        let profileView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        profileView.clipsToBounds = false
        profileView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        let profileImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileView)
        profileImg.customView = profileView

        //NameLabel
        let nameLbl = UILabel()
        nameLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60)
        nameLbl.text = "Hi"
        nameLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 22)
        nameLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        let nameLabel = UIBarButtonItem()
        nameLabel.customView = nameLbl

        //Settings
        let settingsBtn = UIButton()
        settingsBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        settingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Settings-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        settingsButton.customView = settingsBtn

        //Classes
        let classesBtn = UIButton()
        classesBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        classesBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Classes-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        classesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.classesPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let classesButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        classesButton.customView = classesBtn

        //Set buttons
        self.setItems([profileImg, logoImg, nameSpace, nameLabel, spaceButton, classesButton, spaceBetween, settingsButton], animated: false)

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: "ain't"????????

Comment: @matt what do you mean?

Comment: Try using the View Debugger to figure out where the toolbar edges and the bar button items and their custom views really are. They might not be where you think they are...

Comment: @matt They are where they should be using the debug view hierachy: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wigv1et88t1mvn/Schermafdruk%202018-01-31%2015.51.05.png?dl=0

Comment: So when you snapshot the view hierarchy using the View Debugger, the problem doesn't even occur???? The View Debugger shows you a _different layout_ from what you actually see in the running app?????

Comment: @matt Yes. It only occurs when i'm rotating the app. Watch this gif: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7jbmbsuorump5e/spacing-toolbar.gif?dl=0

Comment: But then rotate the app _so that the problem occurs_ and _then_ use the View Debugger! What you want to debug is the _problem_ layout, not the good layout!

Comment: @matt I understand what you'r saying. I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes but the point of the view debugger is not that you take a picture of it. You use it to _analyze_ why your views are where they are. You don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: @matt The View Debugger doesn't give me any data about the spacing inside the toolbar. I do analyze the elements inside the view. I can see where they are, but i can't see WHY they are where they are. On the view after the rotation the debugger shows the toolbar with the extra spacing. But it doesn't show me where this spacing is coming from. Or i'm missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `layoutSubviews` is not the right place to add all the items. For example every time device orientate `layoutSubviews` is called and all items will be created again. Use `init?(coder:)` or `init(frame:)`.

Once you move your code to `init?(coder:)` or `init(frame:)` you will see the left and right margin (currently it appears only when you orientate). This is actual behaviour of `UIToolBar`, It adds margin on both sides automatically.

To remove that margin just add negative separator of fixed size on start and end of toolbar items.

```
let negativeFizedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeFizedSpace.width = -20 // Spacing 20 for iPad and 16 for iPhone
```

---

```
class ToolbarClass: UIToolbar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {

        //Space
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let spaceBetween:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        spaceBetween.width = 1.0

        let nameSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        nameSpace.width = 10

        //Logo
        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "MBS-Logo")
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
        logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -46, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54)
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let logoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54))
        logoView.clipsToBounds = false
        logoView.layer.cornerRadius = logoView.frame.width / 2
        logoView.addSubview(logoImageView)
        let logoImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)
        logoImg.customView = logoView

        //Profile
        let profileImage = UIImage(named: "No-Profile")
        let profileImageView = UIImageView(image: profileImage)
        profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.width / 2
        let profileView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        profileView.clipsToBounds = false
        profileView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        let profileImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileView)
        profileImg.customView = profileView

        //NameLabel
        let nameLbl = UILabel()
        nameLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60)
        nameLbl.text = "Hi"
        nameLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 22)
        nameLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        let nameLabel = UIBarButtonItem()
        nameLabel.customView = nameLbl

        //Settings
        let settingsBtn = UIButton()
        settingsBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        settingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Settings-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        settingsButton.customView = settingsBtn

        //Classes
        let classesBtn = UIButton()
        classesBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        classesBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Classes-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        classesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.classesPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let classesButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        classesButton.customView = classesBtn


        let negativeFizedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeFizedSpace.width = -20 // Spacing 20 for iPad and 16 for iPhone

        //Set buttons
        self.setItems([negativeFizedSpace, profileImg, logoImg, nameSpace, nameLabel, spaceButton, classesButton, spaceBetween, settingsButton, negativeFizedSpace], animated: false)
    }

    //Set height of toolbar
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        size.height = 60
        return size
    }        
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If using Navigation Controller Toolbar. Alternate is to create a `UIViewController` extension to add generic toolbar items and call that in `viewDidLoad` method of your ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addGeneralToolbarItems()
    }
}

class ToolbarClass: UIToolbar {
    //Set height of toolbar
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        size.height = 60
        return size
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func addGeneralToolbarItems()  {
        //Space
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let spaceBetween:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        spaceBetween.width = 1.0

        let nameSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        nameSpace.width = 10

        //Logo
        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "MBS-Logo")
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
        logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -46, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54)
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let logoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 54))
        logoView.clipsToBounds = false
        logoView.layer.cornerRadius = logoView.frame.width / 2
        logoView.addSubview(logoImageView)
        let logoImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)
        logoImg.customView = logoView

        //Profile
        let profileImage = UIImage(named: "No-Profile")
        let profileImageView = UIImageView(image: profileImage)
        profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.width / 2
        let profileView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        profileView.clipsToBounds = false
        profileView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        let profileImg = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileView)
        profileImg.customView = profileView

        //NameLabel
        let nameLbl = UILabel()
        nameLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60)
        nameLbl.text = "Hi"
        nameLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 22)
        nameLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        let nameLabel = UIBarButtonItem()
        nameLabel.customView = nameLbl

        //Settings
        let settingsBtn = UIButton()
        settingsBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        settingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Settings-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        settingsButton.customView = settingsBtn

        //Classes
        let classesBtn = UIButton()
        classesBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 60)
        classesBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Classes-Bar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        classesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.classesPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let classesButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        classesButton.customView = classesBtn


        let negativeFizedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeFizedSpace.width = -20 // Spacing 20 for iPad and 16 for iPhone

        //Set buttons
        self.setToolbarItems([negativeFizedSpace, profileImg, logoImg, nameSpace, nameLabel, spaceButton, classesButton, spaceBetween, settingsButton, negativeFizedSpace], animated: false)

    }

    @objc func settingsPressed() {

    }

    @objc func classesPressed() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this way the toolbar shows no content at all. Also no errors. Beside that, the negative spacer you suggested doesn't work since iOS11. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544961/negative-spacer-for-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-on-ios-11

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine. You are adding `ToolbarClass` in storyboard or nib??

Comment: I'm adding the class in storyboard: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4mhixopcuw8x5k/Schermafdruk%202018-02-04%2016.18.42.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, it is getting called. Also the labels and negative spacers etc.

Comment: can you somehow send me your xcode file with the example?

Comment: See this sample project. Hope it helps.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cv6btfuif3uv91/BarTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you. The difference i noticed is that i'm using a NavigationController with the checkbox 'Shows Toolbar' enabled to add the toolbar. Your example project uses a default ViewController and a toolbar from the library. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes it's makes a lot difference. Navigation toolbar is shared across all the view controllers of a navigation controller. When any view controller is pushed  toolbar items are replaced with the items of the view controller. In this case you can create a ViewController extension to add generic toolbar items and call that in `viewDidLoad` method of your `ViewController`.

Comment: It's working! Your explanation makes sense. Thanks for the answer and your time!